# How to create a conditional based on the existence of an attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

I have the following code in a likes_controller and it works fine as long as a `thing` has an `owner`.  If not, it breaks.

```
  def create
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:like][:liked_id])
    user = @thing.owner
    current_user.like!(@thing)
    current_user.follow!(user)
    respond_with @thing
  end
```

I've tried using

```
user = @thing.owner if @thing.owner.exists?
```

but I get a NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError in LikesController#create

undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I check for the existence of an `owner`?

I also now notice I'll have to put the second line (`current_user.follow!(user)`) in the block or it will break again...

Edit: This worked (using @Amadan's answer):

```
def create
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:like][:liked_id])
    current_user.like!(@thing)
    user = @thing.owner
    if user
      current_user.follow!(user)
    end
    respond_with @thing
  end
```

Additional information: In case anyone ever actually uses this, I should point out that one more small change is necessary to get this to work.  The above code errors out if a `user` tried to `like` a `thing` when they are already `following` the `thing`'s `owner`.

so instead of

```
if user
```

I used

```
if user && !current_user.following?(user)
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this line:

```
return unless user
```

Some might not like it on stylistic grounds, so you can use this alternative:

```
def create
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:like][:liked_id])
  user = @thing.owner
  if user
    current_user.like!(@thing)
    current_user.follow!(user)
    respond_with @thing
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second option, but I changed it up a little bit since I want the user to like the thing regardless of whether it has an owner.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you can do:

```
user = @thing.owner if @thing.owner.present?
```

Comment: I already tried that and got `RuntimeError in LikesController#create

    Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id` which is the same error I get if I don't check at all.

Comment: How is owner defined in your User class? Is this ActiveRecord? Does Thing belong_to Owner?

Comment: It isn't.  It's only defined in the Thing class: `belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"`